# Call to undefined method EE_Localize::human_time() after matrix update

Tags: matrix

After updating matrix to 2.5.9  (EE 2.5.5) I'm getting a blank screen and error message both on the front-end and in the control panel:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Localize::human_time() in /www/eh7377/public_html/cmssystem/expressionengine/third_party/matrix/celltypes/date.php on line 92
```

on an entry form that uses a date field inside a matrix (along with a few other fields).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug specific to the EE 2.5.5 version. It looks like the error was occurring in SuperSearch too in 2.5.5 (http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/17280/#62841) and upgrading to EE v2.6 fixes it.

Comment: Ugh - not looking forward to updating this install. Will report back here if it fixes things. Thnx Anna!

Comment: Can indeed confirm that updating to EE2.7.2 solved the issue.

Comment: Tada... I agree upgrading is a pain but usually fixes these kinds of errors.